# Are there technical limitations that prevent built-ins from having static members?

Tags: c++, language-design

I find this atrocious:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

And really wish I could just write this:

```
int::max
```

Yes, there is `INT_MAX` and friends.  But sometimes you are dealing with something like `streamsize`, which is a synonym for an unspecified built-in, so you don't know whether you should use `INT_MAX` or `LONG_MAX` or whatever.  Is there a technical limitation that prevents something like `int::max` from being put into the language?  Or is it just that nobody but me is interested in it?

Comment: FWIW `std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` works.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Yeah, I know, and I find that one even more atrocious.  My point about `streamsize` is that while INT_MAX is slightly more palatable than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, there is no equivalent STREAMSIZE_MAX.  But if `::max` was a member of `int` and all the other built-ins, then, as a typedef of one of the built-ins, `streamsize` would also have that member.

Comment: Maybe the question could also be presented as: "If some compiler vendor was to implement `int :: max`, would it break any existing code and/or introduce any ambiguities or cause any other problems?"

Comment: I think there's a broader question, which is to list the differences between primitive types and class types. One example is that you can have integral types as parameters to a template `template<int i> ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive types are not class types, so they don't have static members, that's it.

If you make them class types, you are changing the foundations of the language (although thinking about it it wouldn't be *such* a problem for compatibility reasons, more like some headaches for the standard guys to figure out exactly what members to add to them).

But more importantly, I think that nobody but you is interested in it :) ; personally I don't find `numeric_limits` so atrocious (actually, it's quite C++-ish - although many can argue that often what is C++-ish looks atrocious :P ).

---

All in all, I'd say that this is the usual ["every feature starts with minus 100 points"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) point; the article talks about C#, but it's even more relevant for C++, that has already tons of language features and subtleties, a complex standard and many compiler vendors that can put their vetoes:

> One way to do that is through the concept of “minus 100 points”. Every feature starts out in the hole by 100 points, which means that it has to have a significant net positive effect on the overall package for it to make it into the language. Some features are okay features for a language to have, they just aren't quite good enough to make it into the language.

Even if the proposal were carefully prepared by someone else, it would still take time for the standard committee to examine and discuss it, and it would probably be rejected because it would be a duplication of stuff that is already possible without problems.

Comment: Exactly. Java and C# implement such patterns with both types "int" and "Integer", first is a primitive type and second is a class. But C++ is not meant to be used like that.

Comment: @Nanocom: actually, in C# `int` is just a synonym for `System.Int32`, which is a value type, but it still has got static and instance members (but I'm nitpicking).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it would create major compatibility problems?  Because that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: Also, I'm not interested in inheriting from it, so it wouldn't be a class type in that respect.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: hm, actually, thinking again about it, it wouldn't be such a problem, although I wouldn't limit it to just static members (it would be yet another special case for nothing).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: ok for System.Int32 :)

Answer (score 2):

There are actually multiple issues:

1. built-in types aren't classes in C++
2. classes can't be extended with new members in C++
3. assuming the implementation were required to supply certain "members": which? There are lots of other attributes you might want to find for type and using traits allows for them being added.

That said, if you feel you want shorter notation for this, just create it:

```
namespace traits {
    template <typename T> constexpr T max() {
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    }
}

int m = traits::max<int>();

using namespace traits;
int n = max<int>();
```

Comment: 1. How does built-ins not being classes mean they can't have static members?  Is that a technical limitation?  What if we just call them classes?  2. Can you explain how this is relevant?  3. How about the same members that are provided in the numeric_limits class?

Comment: I think the problem is that classes cannot be extended. If statics were defined for the built-in types, every single C++ program would have to link to those built-in statics. Unnecessary bloat?

Comment: @ChrisBednarski: This would be information built into the compiler, just like mathematical operators are built in.  And these would be numeric constants, no bloat.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I realized OK that your intention was that you get what you want even if it requires changing the compiler. That is why the three arguments are provided to explain that it won't fly: 1. members are only defined for classes. Sure, we could make built-ins some sort of classes. This is where 2. applies: even if they were we would need at implementation time what elements shall be provided. So let's assume we know but immediately I came about and blow away any choice in 3.: e.g. I want the SIMD version of the type be a member (if available) as well if there ae members.

Comment: @Benjamin: Static members can also have their own constructors/destructors and then the linker needs to be involved. I guess you're talking about built-in type consts only.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`? As for why it's a function (max()) instead of a constant (max), I don't know. In my own app I made my own num_traits type that provides the maximum value as a static constant instead of a function, (and provides significantly more information than numeric_limits).

It would be nice if they had defined some constants and functions on "int" itself, the way C# has int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue and int.Parse(string), but that's just not what the C++ committee decided.

Comment: I do use `std::numeric_limits::max()`,  but like I said in my post(in the first sentence), I find it atrocious.